# How to create dedicated file of each for loop if/else output of Netmiko access

Tags: python, json, file

I use netmiko to access to each of my Juniper and Cisco devices and run their own commands in for loop. I'm able to access and run the commands and print the output on each loop. I want each output to be save as a file and name it based on ip address. I have test it with sys.stdout=open() but it only able to print and create for one device only and return IO error, which I believed related with the way i open/create the file in loop.

Get print output of devices and create file and save the file based on the ip address on each for loop.

This is my code.

```
for device in devices['mydevice']:
try:
    print('~' * 100)
    print('Connecting to device:',device['ip'])
    connection = netmiko.ConnectHandler(**device)
    if  device['device_type'] == "juniper_junos" :
       print('**********SCAN JUNIPER DEVICES**********')
       sys.stdout=open("Juniper.txt","a")
       print(device['ip'])
       print(connection.send_command('show arp'))
       sys.stdout.close()
       os.rename('Juniper.txt', device['ip'])
    elif device['device_type'] == "cisco_ios" :
       print('**********SCAN CISCO DEVICES**********')
       sys.stdout=open("Cisco.txt","a")
       print(device['ip'])
       print(connection.send_command('show cdp neighbors'))
       print(connection.send_command('show version'))
       sys.stdout.close()
       os.rename('Cisco.txt', device['ip'])
    else :
       print("No valid device type scan")
    connection.disconnect()
except netmiko_exceptions as e:
    print('Failed to ', device['ip'], e)
```

I add sys.stdout=open() and sys.stdout.close() and between those line is the device command. At the end of the loop I rename the file based on ip address.

This code only able to create 1 file of 1.1.1.1 and then return an error as follows

```
Connecting to device: 1.1.1.1
**********SCAN CISCO DEVICES**********
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mydevicessh.py", line 20, in <module>
     print('~' * 100)
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

I think it because the way i open and close the file. 
Please guide and assist further. Thanks

For each ip access it will run the commands and create file and name it based on the ip. for example I have 3 cisco devices and 2 juniper devices, on each for loop it will read ip list and run show arp command for juniper devices and print all the output of the command and then create file such as 1.1.1.1.txt and 1.1.1.2.txt and then for cisco devices it will run command show cdp neighbors and show version and print all the commands output and create file and name 1.1.1.3.txt , 1.1.1.4.txt and 1.1.1.5.txt

I test it below with open() and it run all the commands and save file for only one device 1.1.1.1 and IO error

```
with open('cisco.txt', 'w') as x:
  sys.stdout = x
  file = open('cisco.txt','w')
  file.write(connection.send_command('show cdp neighbors'))
  file.write(connection.send_command('show arp'))
```

Im getting the same error '*ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.*'

Comment: I still not able to create file based on the output, really appreciate some one could show me something. I have no idea right now...blank...Thank you for helping

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use a standar file to write instead of doing it with the stdout?. You can change your code to use a file and file.write. And you don't need to give it a name and when you finish rename it, you can just give the file the final name:

```
for device in devices['mydevice']:
    try:
        print('~' * 100)
        print('Connecting to device:',device['ip'])
        connection = netmiko.ConnectHandler(**device)
        if  device['device_type'] == "juniper_junos" :
           print('**********SCAN JUNIPER DEVICES**********')
           file=open(device['ip']+".txt","a")
           file.write(device['ip'])
           file.write(connection.send_command('show arp'))
           file.close()
        elif device['device_type'] == "cisco_ios" :
           print('**********SCAN CISCO DEVICES**********')
           file=open(device['ip']+".txt","a")
           file.write(device['ip'])
           file.write(connection.send_command('show cdp neighbors'))
           file.write(connection.send_command('show version'))
           file.close()
        else :
           print("No valid device type scan")
        connection.disconnect()
    except netmiko_exceptions as e:
        print('Failed to ', device['ip'], e)
```

Comment: Thanks sir. I need to give a specific name for each file because the devices is multi-vendor and come with their own commands and various output. For example 'show arp' output for cisco and juniper a bit different. Thus, each output of command run for each devices need to be save in a file and specific each file based on IP as i think thats the suitable file name for each devices. Some more, from the saved files I can extract specific data of each devices later.